# What are possible reasons why my jQuery css selector isn't working? How would I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
color = "#123456";
```

```js
$('#a').css('color', "#123456");
$('#b').css('color', "#123456");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input" id="a">
  <input class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 input-co" type="text" value="#ffffff">
</div>
<div class="input" id="b">
  <input class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 input-co" type="text" value="#ffffff">
</div>
```

Is this because this is inline-style and I need to use a `!important` rule? What should I do?

Comment: Can you show us full code ?

Comment: where is your head and body tag

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are setting the color at your container but i suppose you need style the input.

try to catch the input in this way:

```
var color = "#123456";
$('#a input').css('color',color);
$('#b input').css('color',color);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```js
  
$('#a input').css('color', "#123456");
$('#b input').css('color', "#123456");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input" id="a">
  <input class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 input-co" type="text" value="#ffffff">
</div>
<div class="input" id="b">
  <input class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 input-co" type="text" value="#ffffff">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to set the color to your input field not its container or make input inherit its color from its container in css.

```js
var color = 'red',
$firstInput = $('#a .input-co'),
$secondInput = $('#b .input-co');

$firstInput.css('color',color);
$secondInput.css('color',color);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="input" id="a">
        <input class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 input-co" type="text"  value="#ffffff">
    </div>
    <div class="input" id="b">
        <input class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 input-co" type="text"  value="#ffffff">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You did small mistake,

Try like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    color = "#123456";
    $('#a').css('color',color);
   $('#b').css('color',color);
});
```

You have to use jquery code withing document ready.

Your code :

```
color = "#123456";
$('#a').css('color',color);
$('#b').css('color',color);
```

calls when html doc not loaded that's why it's not working.

Comment: *"You have to use jquery code within document ready."* - no, no you don't.  You should ask a question to clarify where the code is being run.  It could be in an event handler (which is not in doc ready) or it could be just before `</body>` which would also work.  It's also not working in the SO snippet, which *does* use (a form of) document ready.